# How to capture ID value from a SelectList item in Razor Pages?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, razor-pages, selectlist

I'm pretty new to web programming in general and am trying to make a simple data entry page using Razor Pages on ASP.Net Core 3.0.

I'm having some trouble with the SelectList in the  tag. The behavior I'm trying to get is capturing the ID value from a SelectList within the view, which is simply refusing to work correctly, at least on the OnPost method.

Here's my code:

[Table Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46pFx.jpg)

[Get the records I need using FromSqlRaw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q39M3.jpg)

[Main table and List of items as IEnumerable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgqvA.jpg)

[Code in the View as SelectList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7tDN.jpg)

[How the list looks on the actual site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keUa4.jpg)

What I really need is to capture the ID value (IDCON) of the list item and post it to the bound property in the asp-for, but for whatever reason the value returned is always null. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or perhaps a different approach?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add `[BindProperty]`,Here is a working demo with fake data.

cshtml:

```
<form method="post">
    <label asp-for="registro.IDCON">Consecuencia</label>
    <select asp-for="registro.IDCON" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.consecuencias,"IDCON","DSCCON"))">
        <option value="">---Elegir Consecuencia---</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="registro.IDCON" class="text-danger"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

cshtml.cs:

```
public class TestIDCONModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public ROCONSEC registro { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public List<ROCONSEC> consecuencias { get; set; }
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            consecuencias = new List<ROCONSEC> { new ROCONSEC { IDCON = 1, DSCCON = "PROCESO RALENTIZADO" }, new ROCONSEC { IDCON = 2, DSCCON = "PROCESO DESTRUIDO" } };
            return Page();
        }
        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            int IDCON = registro.IDCON;
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

It's embarrassing to say that I was having this issue because I had improperly mapped my main table model on the foreign key values. I was mapping directly as an object of the respective table instead of a field type, which at runtime was trying to get the ID from my main table which didn't exist obviously.

That being said it was your contribution that lead me to this realization, when I used Request.Form[""] to check if any value was being passed from the view into the VM, which struck me as odd since it was, but the acceptedValue within the ModelState was null. I rechecked my entire code and finally corrected the issue, now my page is working as intended.

Cheers!